# remove special characters before and after string

Tags: php

Trying to remove the hyphens which come before start of the alphabet and after end of a alphabet, but not to lose the hyphens in between.

1. **Example**

this the string i have

```
---this-is-my-page--
```

output: `this-is-my-page`

Note( no of hyphen are different on each request, it may be many in numbers)

**2. Example**

how to do this,

---this-is-page---

i need to replace the hyphen which is in between string with empty space. but not to loose to the hyphens in start and end.

Answer (score 2):

Use *[trim](https://www.php.net/trim)* function it will work for any number of `-`(hyphen) at start or end of your string,

```
$str = "---this-is-my-page---";
echo $str = trim($str,"-");
```

**Edit**:

And than use `str_replace`,

```
$str = str_replace("-"," ",$str);
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/470uyS)**.

Comment: also how to do this, ---this-is-page--- i need to replace the hyphen which is in between string with empty space

Comment: then all hyphens will be replaced.. but i want to replace only the hyphen in between without triming.

Comment: First trim & than replace, check demo link or post your expected output

Comment: this is expected output is ---this is my page---

Comment: @Parthi04 You can use regex for this. I've posted a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`trim($string, $trimCharacters)`](http://www.php.net/trim):

> trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

```
<?php
    $str = '---this-is-my-page---';
    var_dump( trim($str, '-') ); //string(15) "this-is-my-page"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/9Gnv1NEe)

---

If you **only** want to replace the hyphens inside the string (and not in the start/end) you can use regex:

```
/^(-+)(.*?)(-+)$/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

..and replace it with `(first group)(second group with hyphens replaced)(third group)`.

In code:

```
<?php
    $str = '---this-is-my-page---';

    $str = preg_replace_callback('/^(-+)(.*?)(-+)$/', function($matches) {
        return $matches[1] . str_replace('-', ' ', $matches[2]) . $matches[3];
    }, $str);

    var_dump( $str ); //string(21) "---this is my page---"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/118061)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo trim( "---this-is-my-page---","-");
```

trim removes a character at the and and begin